# Is this correct: "Let me know once you finish"?

Tags: grammar

Please help me. Which of these is correct?

1. *Let me know once you finish*
2. *Let me know when you finish*
3. *Let me know when you have finished.*

Comment: Hi, Happy, and welcome to EL&U. Proofreading is Off Topic here. Please feel free take the site tour and visit the help center for guidance on how to use this site. :)

Comment: This is clearly not a general proofreading question, but a very specific question of which verb tense to use, and thus it should not be closed on those grounds. "*Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern is identified*". By listing several possible choices of verb tense, the OP has clearly (implicitly) identified the source of concern.

Comment: Note: there has been a remarkable change in usage of these phrases historically. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=once+you+finish%2C+once+you+have+finished%2C+when+you+finish%2C+when+you+have+finished&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20finish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20have%20finished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20you%20finish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20you%20have%20finished%3B%2Cc0). Traditionally, only *"when you have finished"* is correct, but in modern grammar, I would say all these choices are.

Comment: @PeterShor +1 for the Ngram. Supplement a reasoned answer with that and post it.

Comment: @njboot: I don't have a reasoned answer. It feels to me that *"when you finish/have finished"* and *"when you arrive/have arrived"* should behave in exactly the same way. But the usage pattern is [completely different](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=once+you+arrive%2Conce+you+have+arrived%2Cwhen+you+arrive%2Cwhen+you+have+arrived&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20arrive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20have%20arrived%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20you%20arrive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20you%20have%20arrived%3B%2Cc0). I'm baffled.

Comment: @PeterShor supplying the ngram in itself provides evidence in support of the claim that the OP's 2nd and 3rd examples are correct. Furthermore, while the 1st may be correct grammatically, the ngram reveals that it's completely non-idiomatic.

Comment: Personally, I would put a comma after *know*, especially in the case of #1.  Presumably you are asking the person to let you know **something** (a something that is understood), after the person finishes (doing something else). You are presumably **not** asking the person to let you know the time & date when s?he finishes (doing something). #2 and #3 could have that latter meaning without a comma, but #1 seems odd to me without a comma.

Comment: Either it **is** a proofreading question, "Which of these is correct?" or it is a question which invites the answer "They are all correct in certain cases". The question needs more context in order to answer the implied "Which of these do I need to use in my specific circumstance?" As it stands it should never have been answered, and the existing answers demonstrate that. And the fact that the OP has asked one question and never returned to accept an answer indicates that none of the answers actually said what he wanted to know.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=once+you+finish%2Conce+you+have+finished%2Cwhen+you+finish%2Cwhen+you+have+finished&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20finish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conce%20you%20have%20finished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20you%20finish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20you%20have%20finished%3B%2Cc0), courtesy of @Peter Shor (slightly modified):
[image]

Based on this Ngram, I'd say that "when" is clearly the preferable adverb in this context. While I don't believe the first sentence is grammatically incorrect, it's awkward.

**Sentences two and three** are idiomatically correct - that being, widely accepted and natural sounding.

Answer (score 2):

It of course also depends on whether it's American English or British English:

British:
[image: British English ngram]
American:
[image: American English ngram]

Answer (score 1):

All three are acceptable; at least without more knowledge of the context.

"when you have finished" possibly implies that the action is more final and firmly in the past than "when you finish" or "once you finish", e.g. "when you have finished your homework, you may play outside" (it must all have been completed properly) vs "when you finish school, I'll collect you" (I'll be waiting for you when the bell rings).